# Is there a Queue deque concept avaliable in thread for OpenCV Videowrite writer

Tags: multithreading, opencv, c++11, image-processing, qimage

I am trying to Write a mp4 file with h264 after writing some text in video frame i have implemented the queue deque concept with boost thread i have tried in both windows and ubuntu. windows with thread in deque works some what fine but same code in Ubuntu based system throws segfault any help will be appreciated

```
void AddQueue(const Mat &image)
{
    m_tempQueue.push(image);
}
void DeQue(string destFile,int width, int height, int fps) //called with thread 
{
    string szFuncName = "VideoOverlay::DeQue";
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_Img_Mutex);

    try {
        VideoWriter videocc(destFile, VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), fps, cv::Size(width, height));
        while (true)
        {
            if (!m_tempQueue.empty()) {
                cv::Mat image(m_tempQueue.front());
                videocc.write(image);

    //          CLog::AddLogDebug(str(boost::format("Pull : %1%") % m_tempQueue.size()));
                if(!m_tempQueue.empty())
                    m_tempQueue.pop();

                if (m_tempQueue.empty() && !m_ProcessQueue)
                {
                    videocc.release();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (!m_ProcessQueue)
            {
                if(videocc.isOpened())
                    videocc.release();
                break;
            }
            //m_Img_Mutex.unlock();
        }
    }catch (...){
        CLog::AddLogDebug(str(boost::format("Error caught at function: %1%")%szFuncName));
//      m_statusCode= 300;
    }
}

//Call method.....
m_thread = std::thread(&VideoOverlay::DeQue, this,destFile,width,height,fps);
//will be called before reading image
```

The deque thread will run until m_ProcessQueue or image is empty at m_tempQueue

I am looking for samples also

Comment: shouldnt you use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_Img_Mutex);` in AddQueue as well? Or is it already in `.push`?

Comment: please review [mre]. if you don't need OpenCV to reproduce the issue, please remove those parts and mock the APIs if necessary.

Comment: Yes i have tried using the m_Img_Mutex in AddQueue  but the the DeQue get locked in the while loop process so i think its geting into death lock condition